# SQL script to bulk update a field depending on a condition

Tags: sql, mariadb, bulk

I have a table with 2 date fields - OperativeTo and OperativeFrom. I have to check for the records for which OperativeTo is missing, then update OperativeTo as follows

```
OperativeTo  = OperativeFrom [Year+1] - 1 day
```

That is, the operative date is equal to the OperativeFrom date of the same record in the following year minus 1 day. e.g. if a record has OperativeFrom date as 1/07/2015 then
OperativeTo will be 30/06/2016.

Comment: Can you provide what you've attempted so far along with what didn't work? This will help us provide better guidance on how to help you

Comment: The only way I could think of is to get all distinct operativeFrom dates and write an update query for each distinct operative date . The concern with this approach  is that each update query may update 5000 records . So if there are 11 distinct  operativeFrom dates then 11 update queries . I'm not sure if this is a good approach

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: The DB I'm working on is MariaDB

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
BEGIN TRAN
SELECT * FROM YourTable
    
    UPDATE YourTable
    SET OperativeTo = DATEADD( DAY, -1, DATEADD( YEAR, 1, OperativeFrom))
    WHERE OperativeTo IS NULL

SELECT * FROM YourTable
ROLLBACK
```

If it gives you desired result, get rid of `BEGIN TRAN/ROLLBACK` and run the query again. Also read about `DATEADD()` [function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Thanks! This is helpful